# Customize auto-completion in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, auto-completion

How can I work with customize completion?
I want to add some new auto-completion but I don't know How the wizard works.
It's here: User>Customize Completion
I don't know what should be writen in the box.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here are a few examples of what I put in the field:

- `\makeatletter` (see [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do))
- `\makeatother`
- `\documentclass{@}` (Texmaker only has `\documentclass[@]{@}` preconfigured)
- `\cref{#label#}` (for the [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package)
- `\Cref{#label#}`
- `\qroof{@}.@` (for the [`qtree`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/qtree) package)

When you start typing one of these commands, Texmaker will offer you matching options for autocompletion, which you can choose between with the arrow keys and select with <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image]

If the command you entered had an `@` placeholder in it (Note: That's Texmaker syntax and has nothing to do with the `@` used in package internal macros), it'll be turned into a `•`, to which you can jump with <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

[image]

The same idea applies for `#bib#` (bibliography items, i.e. items in a .bib file you specified in your document) and `#label#` (created through `\label{labelname}`). Unfortunately, the implementation of the latter seems to be flawed<sub>(note to self: file bug report)</sub>:

[image]

To answer your question succinctly: You can enter whatever macros you're planning on using frequently, using one of the three placeholders Texmaker offers, if necessary.

Comment: Can you prepare a great answer like above for [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145115/how-to-add-new-auto-complete-options-in-texworks) please?

Comment: @HoseynHeydari Unfortunately, I don’t use TeXworks, so I won’t be able to help you here. If you’re looking for a better answer, you could put a [bounty](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on your question, pointing at this answer as a model, if you like.