# How can I do automatic 'environment' of command in 'Texmaker'?

Tags: texmaker, kile

I have knowledge about 'Kile' more or less. Now  I am using 'Texmaker'. But  there is a problem in it. In Kile when we write `\begin{env}` it automatically write `\end{env}` from the following :

Settings => Configure Kile => LaTeX => Environments => making tick mark on "Automatically complete `\begin{env}` with `\end{env}`" we can set it.
But in 'Texmaker' automatic environment is not working. How can I do so.

Answer (score 3):

In Texmaker, you can go to User>Customize Completion and set the \begin{...} and \end{...} that you often use. For example, the tikzpicture environment is not set by default. As I often use it, I have added

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
```

and

```
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Then, when I type \begin{tik , Texmaker gives me \begin{tikzpicture}, I hit tab and I have the \begin{tikzpicture} and \end{tikzpicture} added to my document.

You may find more information at this post: [Customize auto-completion in Texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88726/29987)

Comment: I am using 'Texmaker 1.9.9'. There is no 'Customize Completion' option under 'user'. There are two options under 'user' namely, 'User Tags' and 'User Commands'.

Comment: I'm using texmaker 3.4.1 under mac os. The last version is 4.0.2 and is available here : [download](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html) for all platforms. An update should be helpful.

Comment: My system is 'ubuntu 10.04'. Will this version of ubuntu support'TeXmaker 4.0.2' ?

Comment: I'm not very used to ubuntu but I think that the software center should give you the answer.