# Problem with \begin{}?

Tags: texmaker

i have this question:

When i start write  \begin{... , Latex give me automatically a list of commands to choose, for example it gives,  \begin{ theorem
lemma
proof  ... etc  and when i choose one of them it gives automatically \end{ "the chosen command" }

the problem that it doesn't give \begin{definition}, so i have to write it all by my hands (\begin{definition} and \end{definition})

do someone have any idea about this problem ?

Thank you and sorry for my english

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  That isn't a LaTeX feature, but one of the text editor you use.  Some editors can be extended to know additional environments.  Which editor do you use? (TeXMaker, TeXStudio, ...)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik i am using Texmaker. :)

Comment: Then I think this should have the answer to your question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115159/134574

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik  yes!! It works,  Thank you very much.

Comment: Close and mark as duplicate?

Comment: @BriganosBriganos Glad to know.  I marked your question as a duplicate of that one.