# Changing autocomplete order in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, editors, auto-completion

Does anyone know if it possible to change the autocomplete precedence/order in Texmaker ?  For instance, on my Windows installation, when I begin to type `\begin{al...`, the first thing that pops up is `\begin{align*}`, which is my mostly commonly used environment.  This is great, since I can just type `\begin{al + Tab` and my environment is there.

However, I've been using my Ubuntu version a lot more recently, and the first thing to pop up on the autocomplete list is now `\begin{align}`,  `no star`.  This has made typing a bit irritating, since I now have to remember to hit the up arrow every time.  For some reason I vaguely recall that Texmaker "learns" your behaviour, but I could be making that up ?

Comment: Are the TeXmaker version on Windows and Ubuntu same ? then IDE should behave similar. It autocompletes `align*` on Ubuntu properly although `align` appears first in auto complete list since `align*` is highlighted first, I have noticed `\begin{al` and `Tab` button auto completes `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` on Ubuntu with [TeXmaker 4.0.2](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html).

Comment: @texenthusiast I guess I have version 3.2 on Ubuntu (it's what the Ubuntu software center had).  I'll maybe try installing the newer version, but I suppose the question still stands.

Comment: TeXmaker version might be old on Ubuntu's repository. Remove the old version and then Download [Latest Version:4.0.2](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#linux) installation using [gdebi package installer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Using_GDebi_to_install_packages). [Customize auto-completion in Texmaker](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88726/15717). In my view: Changing autocomplete order in TeXMaker needs changing in [source](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#source) : may be [Feature request](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/).

Comment: Only a suggestion, not an answer. Try to use TeXstudio. In my opinion is better than Texmaker.

Answer (score 2):

Texmaker does not appear to offer a way to alter the order of suggestions for auto-completion. Thus addition of this would seem to be an feature request for the editor. As noted in comments `\begin{align*}` rather than `\begin{align}` seems to be the one selected by default if one types `\begin{al` (tested with version 4.0.3). It is also worth noting that [TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) was forked from Texmaker a few years ago and does have some more sophisticated options to auto-completion, in particular offering separate 'common', 'all' and 'frequently used' lists of results for completion.