# Biblatex - Texmaker auto-complete commands

Tags: biblatex, texmaker

Is there a way to employ auto-completion for Biblatex **commands** (not entries) in Texmaker without writing all commands in User Customization Auto-Completion manually?

Comment: Just to get this straight: Do you want to auto-complete *commands* such as `\cite` and `\autocite`, or do you want to auto-complete `.bib` entries such that if you cite `\cite{si` a list pops up where you can select `sigfridsson`?

Comment: Thank you @moewe I realized that the other question was on auto-complete of the bib-entries. Mine is on the commands.

Answer (score 2):

If you want TeXmaker to autocomplete commands that it does not already know, you need to add these commands manually via User > Customize Completion", see [How can I make texmaker autocomplete commands that it doesn't already autocomplete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185935/35864). To add `\autocite` for example you could add

```
\autocite{#bib#}
```

in that dialogue window.

TeXmaker also automatically adds all `.bib` entries it can find to the autocomplete list (note that not all `.bib` files are found automatically, if they reside in a different folder from your `.tex` file, you may have to tell TeXmaker about that even though BibTeX/Biber can find the `.bib` file just fine).

---

TeXstudio (a fork of TeXmaker if I understand correctly) seems to have slightly more sophisticated autocomplete feature. It can automatically detect which set of auto-complete commands to provide. The `biblatex` autocomplete list seems very comprehensive and already has all the common commands available.

Comment: Yes, I already know how to use auto-complete by entering all these commands in the User Customize Completion. My question was if there is a way to get all the Biblatex commands into auto-completion without typing them on my own. Furthermore, what bothers me is, that when you have the auto-complete instead of showing the first command with a placeholder it suggests the first, second, third entry and so on and the command with the placeholder at last. Is there a way to change this? Also auto-completion does not work if you for example enter additional arguments like \autocite[cf.][@]{#bib#}.

Comment: @D.P. No, as far as I am aware there is no way to tweak the auto-complete in TeXmaker further, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123481/35864. If you are not dead-set on TeXmaker and want a similar editor with better auto-complete you can try TeXstudio. Or you can ask the TeXmaker developers to include new features for the autocomplete. BTW: `\autocite[cf.][@]{#bib#}` worked just fine for me.

Comment: I guess I will switch to Vim. Everytime I create elements like box brackets before the curly brackets, as in `\autocite[cf.][@]{#bib#}`, it does not suggest to me the entries anymore.

Comment: @D.P. Mhhh, as I say, this works for me. Surely this is a bug you should report to the developers if you have made sure that it also happens in the latest release version and is consistently reproducible. You don't need to make the radical step to move to vim, you could also try TeXstudio (a fork of TeXmaker with enhanced autocomplete - amongst others),