# Auto-completion for (only) \citet using bibtex and natbib using texmaker does not work

Tags: natbib, texmaker, auto-completion

I am using bibtex and natbib for a scrartcl and the editor texmaker and everything works fine, except that I don't have auto-completion for (only) the command `\citet`. For `\citep` it works just fine. And both citation commands also do work. It's just a question of convenience for me.
How do I get auto-completion to work here?
Here's the tex file code (text reduced to a minimum):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,~}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{\fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{blindtext}



%----------------end-of-preamble----------------
%---------------begin-of-document---------------


\begin{document}

\section{Local Density Estimator}
Considering only equal-mass stars, \citet{vonhoerner1963} defined the local mean density around a star as ...

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{/home/hmm/bib/clusters}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Auto-completion of the citation key is a feature of the text editor. You did not mention which editor you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I added that I am using texmaker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I posted the issue on the [website recommended](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list) and got a very helpful reply:

Updates:
 Status: Done
Comment #1 on issue 1306 by ... : Auto-completion for \citet
http://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=1306
You can add what you want for the auto-completion :
"User" menu -> "Customize completion" : \citet{#bib#}

I wasn't aware that you could do that. It works perfectly now.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad advice I gave to you.

Comment: Oh, don't worry about it! In the end, it pointed me to the correct answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

<del>As far as I can tell, the list of citation commands recognized by Texmaker cannot be configured by the user.</del> The source code of Texmaker 4.2 has three occurrences of `citep` but `citet` is not mentioned. Update: However, as pointed out by the original poster, the auto-completion list is customizable. I should have done more research before answering this one. There is also a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88726/23160) on TeX.SE.

<del>You could post a feature request in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list) of Texmaker.</del>