# redefine \ref{...} commands - TeXMaker ref auto-completion

Tags: cross-referencing, texmaker, auto-completion

I am redefining my reference command, to more easily reference chapters, tables, figures, etc.. Here e.g. for chapters

```
\newcommand{\CHAPREF}[1]{chapter \ref{#1}}    %Reference template for chapter
```

So that I can simply type

```
\chapter{A chapter}
\label{chp:chapter}
This is a reference to \CHAPREF{chp:chapter}
```

Which will result in

```
This is a reference to chapter 1.
```

But this way I can not use auto-completion in TeXMaker anymore, which would usually propose some chapter references when only typying \ref{...

Is there any way to make TeXMaker also auto complete these new commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googleing for some time, posting this question, I now finally found the correct key words to search for...

Here is the solution:

In TeXMaker, select

```
User > Customize Completion
```

and add another entry like

```
\CHAPREF{#label#}
```

This will add auto-completion to the CHAPREF command like to the ref command.

EDIT: See also [Customize auto-completion in Texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88726/customize-auto-completion-in-texmaker)