# How to use a macro to create a label for figures?

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, texmaker

There's another question that provides the answer I think should work ([Automated label tagging in figure? Automated labeling?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123509/automated-label-tagging-in-figure-automated-labeling)), but even when I directly copy and paste that code, the `\ref` function just shows my figures being labelled as `fig:#1` rather than `image_1`.

Here's the code that's not working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{/FieldNotes/}}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
%\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption} 

\newcommand\fig[2]{
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{#1}
  \caption{#2} 
  \label{fig:#1}
\end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\fig{image_1}{1} % 
\fig{image_2}{2} % 


\end{document}
```

I'm using the most recent versions of Texmaker and MiKteX

**EDIT:** I'm asking why when I use `\ref` the only labels that it's recognising are `fig:#1` and `fig:#2` rather than the `fig:image_1` and  `fig:image_2` that I think it should be recognising.

**EDIT 2:** Got it working now, thanks!

Comment: are you asking about the `\label{fig:image_1}` which you set but do not use, as you have no `\ref{fig:image_1}` or are you asking about `\caption{1}` which is legal if weird as it produces **Figure 1:1** normally you would have `\caption{some text describing the figure}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the `\caption` works fine (I just used 1 as a quick example caption), but when I then type `\ref` in the actual body of the document, it only suggests `\ref{fig:#1}` or `\ref{fig:#2}` rather than the `\ref{fig:image_1}` that I think it should produce?

Comment: did you run latex twice?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah I've run it a few times (quick build) but even after that it's still not recognising `fig:image_1` or `fig:image_2`

Comment: Do you mean the auto-completion function of your editor?

Comment: Oh you are asking about the editor not about latex??? The editor can only make guesses based on commands it knows, if you hide the label in a definition it will not see it. It may have an editor specific customisation to say the argument of `\fig` is a label.

Comment: Ah I've got it working now. The editor itself wasn't showing anything for the reference, and initially latex wasn't recognising it either but I think I might've just spelled something wrong as it's working now!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224021/redefine-ref-commands-texmaker-ref-auto-completion

Answer (score 0):

It is not too clear what your question is, as you show no `\ref` but perhaps this will get you started

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newcommand\fig[2]{%
\begin{figure}%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{#1}%
  \caption{#2}% 
  \label{fig:#1}%
\end{figure}%
}

\begin{document}

\fig{example-image-a}{An example}% 
\fig{example-image-b}{Another example}% 


See Figures \ref{fig:example-image-a} and \ref{fig:example-image-b}.

\end{document}
```