# Adding a command to the pop up list

Tags: editors, auto-completion

When we start writing some LaTeX command, a pop shows the complete command. Is there some way to add a command e.g. `\bibitem` to this list so that we will not have to write complete command frequently.

Comment: This is a tool from your LaTeX editor. Which one are you using?

Comment: I am using Texmaker 4.4.1

Comment: I'm almost sure that you can go to Options menu and Configure and then you can set up the Autocompletion tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For customized commands in TeXMaker add them to your customized completion list.
In TeXMaker menu go to

```
User > Customize Completion
```

Here you can add a new command, which should be available in auto-completion then.

See also [Customize auto-completion in Texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88726/customize-auto-completion-in-texmaker) for more detailed example.