# Autocomplete glossary in TexMaker

Tags: texmaker, glossaries, auto-completion

I use glossaries in my project and would like to be able to autocomplete whenever i write `\gls{@}` and `\glspl{@}`, where the autocomplete makes suggestions based on the entries in my glossary.tex file.

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88726/customize-auto-completion-in-texmaker?newreg=535990a2a06b4d34950dc666853bbd3a) shows how to do it for labels and citations, but I would like to include glossary suggestions if possible.

Thanks.