# Autocompletion in Texmaker for \citeA command

Tags: texmaker, auto-completion, apacite

Texmaker suggest a list of all bibtex-keys when typing the beginning of `\citep{•}`. I use APACite and therefore often need `\citeA{•}` though.

First: Is it possible to make texmaker suggests for `\citeA{•}`?

Second: How can the suggestions for  `\citep{•}` be turned off (have to scroll through all of them to get the suggestions of `\cite{•}`)?

Comment: You can do this via `User` --> `Customize Completion` as described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88729/134144.
In your case, you would need to add `\citeA{#bib#}`.

Comment: Your question and answer will not be deleted. So people looking specifically for this will presumably find it. How many distinct packages/macros are there for which people might want autocompletion? Literally thousands. It makes no sense to have a question for each package/macro combination that someone might want to make an autocompletion for. `apacite` + `\citeA` is just one such combination.  It's not special in any particular way.

Comment: Thank you @leandriis for answering the first part of the question. Any suggestions on how to suppress the built-in auto-completion  for `\citep{•}`?

Comment: @AlanMunn please unmark as a duplicate since the question has been edited so that everybody sees the difference to the falsely accused duplicate.

Comment: @InDubio Your second question is effectively answered by [How to disable \citep](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/229457)  i.e., there's no way to affect the built-in completions. See also [Changing autocomplete order in Texmaker](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/123481) which suggests that switching to TeXStudio might be a better option.